# Controlling permissions for app team while assigning them ALTER ANY AG access

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2017

There is a need where we our DEV team needs to make index changes and run other index maintenance jobs on the primary replica. We have seen that while this happens, there is a blocking chain created on readable secondary replica due to DDL comings from primary.

To mitigate we tested to making change to the secondary replica's readable state.  change to `SECONDARY_ROLE (ALLOW_CONNECTIONS = NO)` and later flip it back to `SECONDARY_ROLE (ALLOW_CONNECTIONS = READ_ONLY)`.

We, as PROD DBAs have sysadmin access to do so. But, to avoid this manual work, we asked developers to add a code in their process to turn off readable replica before starting their changes and once done simply turn it back on. We are aware this disconnects the secondary users but we are fine with it.

However, to make this change we need to give them the following server level permissions.

```
ALTER ANY AVAILABILITY GROUP;

ALTER ANY DATABASE;
```

This does not seem like a good security practice. We can create a role to assign this permission, but is there a better way of approaching this? Maybe there is something we are overlooking, like within app code to add some temporary way of getting access and then revoking once done?

Comment: Let’s focus on your real problem, which seems to be devs running index maintenance in prod. Why not look to take over index maintenance from them. After all, they’re probably trying to rebuild every index every day.

Comment: @BrendanMcCaffrey: I will say they are more of DEV DBA's and i am mostly in security or prod DBA